# Error while uploading Image and image name in database, codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

There is an error while uploading an image in Codeigniter. The file name noimage is saved in the database.

**// Upload Image Controller**

```
      $config['upload_path'] = './assets/Images/profilepictures';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
      $config['max_size'] = '2048';
      $config['max_width'] = '2000';
      $config['max_height'] = '2000';

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
          $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
          $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
      } else {
          $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
          $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
      }

      $this->m_user->profilepicture($post_image);
      if($data['user']->profile_pic==null)
      {
            redirect(base_url().'user/profilepicture/');

      }
```

**Model**

```
    public function profilepicture($post_image){
$userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
            $data = array(
            'profile_pic' => $post_image,
            );
      $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
      $this->db->update('users', $data);
    }
```

Comment: can you show us your $errors and $data values before the model called?

Comment: The problem is it is successfully running if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) so noimage.jpg is getting inserted in the database. SO no error.

Comment: ok after success what is $post_image value before the model called?

Comment: noimage.jpg is the value

Answer (score 0):

Your Image Name is not inserting in the database, because in your update query, you have not passed the **$userID** value.

**Changes in Model =>**

```
public function profilepicture($userID,$post_image)  //Pass $userID here from Controller.
{
    $data = array(
        'profile_pic' => $post_image,
    );
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
}
```

**Changes in Controller =>**

```
$userID = $data['user']->user_id;  //Add this line.

$this->m_user->profilepicture($userID,$post_image);  //Update here
```

Your page is redirected because `profile_pic` is always **null** as it isn't updated in database. So after you successfully insert `profile_pic` in your database, your page will not redirected to `redirect(base_url().'user/profilepicture/');`.

Comment: I've just edited, the problem is its not just uploading the image.

Answer (score 0):

When the image is not uploading try to redirect back to the form and don't add `noimage.jpg` to database

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
      $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      //Redirect to form with error message
  } else {
      //Get image name like this
      $data = $this->upload->data();
      $post_image = $data['file_name'];

      //Call model function only when image successfully uploaded
      $this->m_user->profilepicture($post_image);
  }
```

Call model function only when image successfully uploaded

So, remove this condition `if($data['user']->profile_pic==null)`